# Importing project in a new eclipse workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a new workspace cause the the previous was full and it took a lot of time to rebuild it every changes I made in a project.
I tried to import some projects File>Import>Existing project into Workspace but when I choose the root director I got some projects cannot imported cause they already exist in your workspace. The incredible is that the workspace has only 2 projects but not those. 
Besides, I found that every project is still named after the first one I used how base.
I mean that after developing one project I made a copy in the folder, renamed it and then build a new project using the resources as well as changing package name in the manifest.
How can I import the project and get rid of this old path? Maybe is something in library files? But I am a novice in developing you can see from the screen shot that all project are referred to the same name. Thanks for helping me.

[image]

Comment: I really don't understand your situation. Can you please explain exactly what you did (copying and stuff) and what you want to do now and how you're trying to do it?

Comment: who ever down-voted i just hope they are aware of this http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/576/why-did-my-reputation-decrease

Comment: Ok. Point 1) I created a new workspace and want to import only some of the projects I have in the old one but when I try with the import  got the picture above. It says that project already exists. Point 2) I used to copy a project in the folder, rename it then from Eclipse create a new project using existing resources. I renamed the manifest package and refactor folder name but I don't know why it appears the same project called CORSOMC5. How can I import the project or get rid of this inconvenient of the name CORSOMC5 recurring in any project?

Comment: And what about if you copy your project from old workspace to new workspace and then use import project?

Comment: It's the same Warning message and greyed files. What is strange is that I don't import this CORSOMC5 project but it is in the workspace2 how it was a referenced project but all projects haven't any references except the general android 2.2 library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was simple after some months to explain. I got greyed projects because they weren't in the workspace I supposed to be but in the other folder and in the workspace2 there were only the project not the source. I solved it copying the full folder in the new workspace using resource explorer then I started Eclipse and create a new project with File>General>create project from existing source then I browsed to the new directory and selected the folder project. That's all.